# Can i able to view my table design and contents in Sqlite?

Tags: node.js, angular, sqlite, cordova, ionic3

I am a beginner in Ionic ,so now am trying to modify a ionic project created by someone.
I am using ionic v3.13.2
and cordova v 7.1.0
I use angular4 for the client side

Now i need to know about the tables created by the previous person and also  need to see what are all the contents in it

Is it possible to check the table design and list the contents in sqlite like we used in sql server?

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite - best viewer on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047799/sqlite-best-viewer-on-mac)

Comment: Before directly posting such question here, please search on Google or Stackoverflow. Here is already very popular post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047799/sqlite-best-viewer-on-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/)  or [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to view the tables and contents as you do with sqlserver.